# select content of column in draggable jqGrid

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, free-jqgrid, tablednd

My goal is to able select the column content in draggable jQgrid.

so I have the idea to make able or disable the drag&drop option in jqGrid ( I'm using free jqGrid).

for make it able, i have used the simple follwing code:

```
$("#jqGrid-11").tableDnDUpdate();
```

for disable the drag&drop, I tried with the follwing code:

```
 $("#jqGrid-11" +" tr").addClass('nodrag nodrop');
 $("#jqGrid-11" + " tr").css("cursor", "text"); 
 $("#jqGrid-11" + " tr").removeClass('tDnD_whileDrag');
```

it make the cursor as pointer to select but it not possible to select the content

Any idea?

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What do you mean when you say select the "content" of a column? Do you want the values inside each cell of a specific column? Or do you want to highlight a specific cell? Or do you want to disable dragging when the mouse is over a particular cell?

Comment: I want to say the values inside each cell of a specific column

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way to get the values of columns because columns aren't really a "thing" in HTML, however, you can use jQuery to get at the nth-child like this:

`$('#jqGrid-11 > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3)'`

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/DenisHo/xpvt214o/624869/ to get you started.